# TypeScript types exported from one package are aliasing to "any" when imported into another package

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have two Rush packages inside of a monorepo. Lets call them `Package-A` and `Package-B`.

There are some TS type definitions that live in `Package-A` that I want to be able to access within `Package-B`.

#### The Setup

##### Package-A

```
// Package-A/src/index.ts

export * from './types';
```

```
// Package-A/src/types.ts

import type { Props as PackageAComponentPropsForExport } from '~/components/PackageAComponent';

export type PackageAComponentProps = PackageAComponentPropsForExport;
```

```
// Package-A/src/components/PackageAComponent

export type Props = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
```

`tsconfig.json` for `Package-A`:

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx",
    "./types/**/*.ts",
    "./types/**/*.d.ts",
    "./*.js",
    "./.*.js",
    "./*.json",
    "./.*.json"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cjs",
    "lib"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./types"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2020"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "plugins": [{
      "transform": "@zerollup/ts-transform-paths"
    }],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest",
    ]
  }
}
```

##### Package-B

```
// Package-B/src/app/index.tsx

import type { PackageAComponentProps } from 'Package-A';

//  I expect this to error, but instead it says it is aliased to 'any'. 
const test: PackageAComponentProps = {};
```

#### The Problem:

When I import the types into `Package-B`, the types are found / can be imported, however they do not contain any type information. The seem to be aliased to `any`, and I do not get type hinting in my editor.

I have tried to export the types in a variety of different ways, including:

1. exporting them directly:

```
// Package-A/src/types.ts

export type { Props as PackageAComponentPropsForExport } from '~/components/PackageAComponent';
```

2. exporting them as a named alias:

```
// Package-A/src/types.ts

import type { Props as PackageAComponentPropsForExport } from '~/components/PackageAComponent';
export type PackageAComponentProps = PackageAComponentPropsForExport;
```

3. exporting them using `import()` syntax:

```
// Package-A/src/types.ts

export type PackageAComponentProps = import('~/components/PackageAComponent').Props;
```

...however, I get the same result with all three. It seems to just export the type but alias its typing information to `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json`, you need to set `"declaration": true`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true, // generate typings
    "declarationMap": true, // generate source maps, if desired
    "declarationDir": "types", // explicit directory
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

The `tsc` will automatically resolve and export the necessary `.d.ts` files. You shouldn't need to export anything from your module except for the API by which people will utilization your module.